# Codeigniter updating records

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'm having some trouble updating records with the Codeigniter framework. I'm using the MVC pattern and active records.

The code is for updating user profiles.

In my model, `Profile_model` I have a function to update...

```
function profile_update() 
    {
        $this->db->where('user_id', 2);
        $this->db->update('user_profiles', $data);              
    }
```

The controller `Profile_crud` should retrieve data from a form and send the data to the model.

```
function update() 
    {
        $data = array (
            'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
            'website' => $this->input->post('website')         
        );

        $this->load->model('Profile_model');
        $this->Profile_model->profile_update($data);
    }
```

and the form in my view `profile.php` On submit it triggers the `update` function in my controller.

#### Update

```
<?php echo form_open('profile_crud/update'); ?>

<p>
<label for="country">Country</label>
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="website">Website</label>
<input type="text" name="website" id="website" />
</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

When I submit the form I get 3 types of errors.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: models/profile_model.php
>
> Line Number: 27

line 27 is `$this->db->update('user_profiles', $data);`

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home1/requestg/public_html/housedwork/system/libraries/Exceptions.php:166)
>
> Filename: codeigniter/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 356

and

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> You must use the "set" method to
>   update an entry.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.. Can someone please help?

Comment: BTW, it's a bad idea to insert your inputs without validation, CI makes it a very easy task using the [Form Validation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) library.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your `profile_update` function, you are specifying the argument of `$data`:

```
$this->Profile_model->profile_update($data);
```

But in your model function, you have not specified one:

```
function profile_update() 
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', 2);
    $this->db->update('user_profiles', $data);              
}
```

It should be:

```
function profile_update($data) 
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', 2);
    $this->db->update('user_profiles', $data);              
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your profile_update() is missing $data parameter

```
function profile_update($data) 
{
    $this->db->where('user_id', 2);
    $this->db->update('user_profiles', $data);              
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your model `Profile_model` haven't received any parameter.

```
function profile_update($data) {
    return $this->db
       ->where('user_id', 2)
       ->update('user_profiles', $data);
}
```